# Replacating a file with different string for test purposes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following file which calls an endpoint and saves the result in a json file in order to perform a benchmark on my algorith.

```
import requests
import json
import simplejson

r =     requests.get('http://localhost:5000/get_jobs/accurate,detail%20oriented,n     mbers,finance,analyst,optimistic,emotional%20intelligence,positive,calm,resilient,stable,committed,competitive,ambitious,determined,targets,goal-oriented,quick%20learner').json()

f = open('ProfileA.json', 'w')
simplejson.dump({'this is a test on Profile A with the following words: accurate,detail%20oriented,numbers,finance,analyst,optimistic,emotional%20intelligence,positive,calm,resilient,stable,committed,competitive,ambitious,determined,targets,goal-oriented,quick%20learner' : r}, f,sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
f.close()
```

I am wondering if there is any method in python where I can simply replicate the file with a random string generator.

I was thinking of ways and for example maybe a regex that picks up strings and if it finds that string will write to another file with a new string but sounds really inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you save the JSON locally and then open it with simplejson?

Comment: @BenQuigley I am saving it locally but I am not sure how this is related to my question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash to map things to fixed length of string:

```
import hashlib

hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(info).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

where `info` is your stuff, either `dict`, `str`, ...